# Why does this Python Reddit API call fail?

Tags: api, python-3.x, reddit

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. I am trying to use the requests module to interact with Reddit's APIs, but for some reason I am getting HTTP status `403` codes. I am able to successfully log in I believe (since I get HTTP 200), but I cannot perform a successful API request. I am very new to this so please use small words. Thanks.

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

# URLs
url_base = r'https://www.reddit.com'
url_login = '/api/login'
 url_me = '/api/v1/me'

# Credentials
user = '__kitten_mittens__'
passwd = 'password'
params = {'user': user,
          'passwd': passwd,
          'api_type': 'json',}

headers = {'user-agent': '/u/__kitten_mittens__ practice api bot'}

# Set up the session/headers
client = requests.session()
client.headers = headers

response = client.post(url_base + url_login, data = params)
j = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
mh = j['json']['data']['modhash']
print("The modhash for {USER} is {mh}".format(USER=user, mh=mh))

# THIS CODE GIVES HTTP STATUS CODE 403
response = client.get(url_base + url_me)
me_json = json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
pprint(me_json)
```

EDIT: I fixed the missing single quote from the password field. That was not part of the problem.

Comment: I found this tool helpful when integrating with APIs on widows. There are similar ones for other platforms too. They are very handy. [im-only-resting](https://github.com/SwensenSoftware/im-only-resting)

Comment: Have you tried using [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/)?  It handles a lot of the annoying parts of interacting with the API.